# Laravel Sessions LifeTime Issues

Tags: laravel, session, lifetime

Laravel Session Lifetime is not working it is stuck on 2 hours I have tried to reduce it and to increase it as well  but when I login an check the cookies expiry it still shows 2 hours for the expiry of a session 
any help would be appreciated 
example below

```
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 180),

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Chrome Cookies
Accessible to script
No (HttpOnly)
Created
Friday, June 7, 2019 at 8:43:25 AM
Expires
Friday, June 7, 2019 at 10:43:25 AM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Check your .env file first make sure you was config SESSION_LIFETIME
2. run this command :

   php artisan config:clear

Comment: it works indeed, but why is session.php ignored?

Answer (score 1):

you need to clear cache

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: yes but the issue was env file lifetime time Anyways thankyou so much :)